# Declare variables in Oracle. update values and then use in select statement

Tags: oracle, variables, report

I am trying to write a report in Oracle that defines / declares variables, updates the values based on 'something' and then uses those values in a select statement. I could do this in 5 minutes in SQL but am having problems doing it in Oracle. I have tried using define and declare and cant get it working. I am using Toad for Oracle.
I dont mind if we use define or declare (or something else), hopefully the below gives you an idea of what i am trying to do:

```
=============
--declare variables
declare or define var1 number;
var2 varchar2(10) := extract (x from tableY);
var3 number:=100;


--update values based on value of var2
begin 
if var2 = 'ABC' then
select 123 into var1 from dual;
 else
select 456 into var1 from dual; 
select 200 into var2 from dual;
end if;
end


--run report based on values

select 
Total-var1 as new_total
from Table 
where
total/var1 >100
and id < ID/var3  
==============
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are.

Sample tables first (so that PL/SQL code doesn't fail because of that):

```
SQL> create table tabley as select 'ABC' x from dual;

Table created.

SQL> create table sometable as
  2  select 500 id, 1000 total from dual;

Table created.
```

Anonymous PL/SQL block:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    --declare variables
  3    var1      number;
  4    var2      varchar2(10);
  5    var3      number := 100;
  6    new_total number;
  7  begin
  8    -- populate VAR2; if table contains more than a single row, SELECT will
  9    -- return TOO_MANY_ROWS error; hence the WHERE clasue
 10    select x into var2 from tabley where rownum = 1;
 11    --update values based on value of var2
 12    if var2 = 'ABC' then
 13       select 123 into var1 from dual;
 14    else
 15       select 456 into var1 from dual;
 16       select 200 into var2 from dual;
 17    end if;
 18
 19    --run report based on values
 20    select
 21      Total - var1
 22    into new_total
 23    from someTable
 24    where total/var1 >100
 25      and id < ID/var3;
 26
 27    dbms_output.put_line('New total = ' || new_total);
 28
 29  exception
 30    when no_data_found then
 31      dbms_output.put_Line('Select did not find anything');
 32  end;
 33  /
Select did not find anything

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```